# Retrieve a single row or cell from MySQL result set

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok so Im just fine making a query and outputting the entire result set.  What I need is to just select a single row of a result set so as to avoid making a whole new query for that single row/cell.  For example

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM books";
$query_result = mysql_query($query,$connection);
while($book = mysql_fetch_array($query_result){
 output... (have no problem outputting the whole result set) 
}
```

Im just wondering what it would take to select a single row of the result set...or a single cell without making a whole new query.  Thanks so much!

Comment: did you forget the `$` on the `book`?

Comment: `SELECT somefield FROM ...`, then `echo $book['somefield']`?

Comment: ok listen, the question is not how to make the query.  I got that.  The issue is just outputting a single row/cell of the result set.  The reason is because I have a project right now where I have to compile a list of books for a select list.  down the page, I need a specific book name from the result set.  Im trying to avoid creating another query.  Is it possible?

Comment: please stop using the outdated `mysql_*` functions and learn to use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are selecting all your rows anyway but also need some particular row beside the whole result set, you can save it in a variable

```
while(book = mysql_fetch_array($query_result){  
  if (some condition) {
    $var = $row['col'];
  }
} 
echo $var;
```

Comment: +1 because I think this is what the question is about, not about adjusting the sql query

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer would be a 'where' clause.

$query="
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE books.title='SQL for Dummies'
";

Answer (score 0):

You get a single row if you use

```
SELECT * FROM books LIMIT 1
```

You probably want to add an ORDER BY to have control on *which* single row is returned. for example:

```
SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY date_published DESC LIMIT 1
```

If you don't want all columns from the table, just replace the `*` with the list of desired columns, e.g.:

```
SELECT author, title
FROM books 
ORDER BY date_published DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If what your after is to retrieve the full set, but only process a single row, you'd simply need to skip the `while`-loop.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array ($query_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to get single row:

```
SELECT * FROM books LIMIT 1
```

Or,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM books";
$query_result = mysql_query($query,$connection);

$book=$query_result[0];
```

//$book having first row of result